# When Agasthya Rishi (Vaman Avtar) got the Sri Lanka as prize?

Tags: vedas, agastya, ramayana

When Agasthya Rishi visited Mahabali, then the King MahaBali gifted Sri Lanka to him. Agasthya ji is also called Vaman Avtar of Vishnu.

So the question is did he got this prize land before Visheshrava (Father of Ravan) or Pulatsya Rishi (Grand Father of Ravan).

Comment: Where are you getting this information?

Comment: "Agasthya ji is also called Vaman Avtar of Vishnu" -- never heard this earlier, which scripture says so??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Vaman is not name it means Dwarf. During Mahabali times, only one super genius Sage existed named Agasthya. He hid his name from Mahabali and challenged all his experts vedic pundits.. Also, Agastya name is mentioned in Valmiki Ramayan. Agasthya went to south and created many language and scripts.. Vaishnav consider him as Vishu (Vaman) and Shaivites consider him as partly Avtar or Shiv. It is mouth to mouth folklore.

Comment: If this is valid, it's an earlier happening to Rāvaṇa, because we clearly know that after Rāvaṇa, Laṅkā would be ruled by Vibhīṣaṇa till the ending of kalpa.

Comment: Bhagwan Raam knows or History knows. I feel that Agasthya Bhagwaan might have made Kuber as a caretaker king, but then Ravan snatched away from him.